# Access Ubuntu Samba shared folder from outside VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, samba, lan, nat

I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04 on VirtualBox with Windows 11 as host.

I set a "NAT" adapter in Virtualbox and forwarded the ports 80 and 443 from the host to the guest for an Apache server and I can reach it from all over the host LAN.

I then installed Samba but the problem is that when I try to access Samba ports from the host LAN there is a "conflict" with the Windows host sharing ports. Basically when I try to connect to smb://IP Windows does reply and not Ubuntu inside the VM. How can I solve this conflict?